# Split string into lines

Tags: vba, split, line

I want to split a string into lines. For a long time I was using

```
Split(myString, vbCrLf)
```

But now I ran into some problems because there are different characters used for a new line. I want to match all those characters (\n and \r\n, ...). What shall I do?

Comment: You could replace all line ends, like vbCr vbCrLf or chr(10) chr(13) etc.. with a character and then split by that, or split, then split again...

Answer (score 5):

Replace them all with another character. In this example I'll use `Chr(19)` which is an uncommon ASCII character.

```
myString = Replace(myString, vbCr, Chr(19))
myString = Replace(myString, vbLf, Chr(19))
myString = Replace(myString, vbCrLf, Chr(19))

'// Remove any doubled up Chr(19)
While InStr(myString, Chr(19) & Chr(19))
    myString = Replace(myString, Chr(19) & Chr(19), Chr(19))
Wend

'// Remove any trailing Chr(19) if present
y = Split(Left$(myString, Len(myString) - IIf(Right$(myString, 1) = Chr(19), 1, 0)), Chr(19))

For Each s In y
    Debug.Print s & ": " & Len(s)
Next
```

Comment: Can you tell me what vbCr, vbLf and vbCrLf are in \n notation?

Comment: `vbCr` is **c**arriage **r**eturn (`\r`) and `vbLf` is a **l**ine **f**eed (`\n`). `vbCrLf` is a **c**arriage **r**eturn followed by a **l**ine **f**eed (`\r\n`).

Comment: So that means your code does "line1\r\nline2" -> "line1\r\n\nline2" -> "line1\r\r\n\r\nline2" before splitting?

Comment: Okay, I didn't know that it is parsed as single character. What I described in my comment above was replacing, not appending. But I understood `\r\n` as two characters.

Comment: Yeah, it's wrong what you said. `Debug.Print (vbCrLf=Replace(vbCrLf,vbLf,vbCrLf))` returns `false`.